# Product Quickview Not Displaying Correctly

Tags: javascript, shopify, product, liquid

When I click on any quick view button on any product in a collection page then it doesn't displays the variant properly, instead it only displays "[object Object]" on every variant. Any solution??
[Image Preview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uKK6l.jpg)

I have 2 files related to quick view products,
one is in Snippets folder (product-quick-view.liquid)
other is in Assets folder (quickview.js)

The code of (product-quick-view.liquid) is

```
<div id="quick-view" class="hidden-label br-product-popup hidden">
  <div class="quickview-wrapper">
    <div class="quick-modal show">
      <div class="content" id="quickview-content">
        <a href="javascript:void(0)" class=" close-window close-btn quickview-close"></a>
        <div class="single-product-detail">
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6">
              <div class="product-media thumbnai-left">
                <div class="featured-image product-single-photos br-product__media br-product-slide-vertical-image pb-0" style="margin-bottom: 5px;"></div>
                <div class="more-views owl-carousel-play pt-5 {% if settings.enable_rtl %}engoc_no_rtl{% endif %}">
                  <div class="owl-carousel"  data-items="4" data-dots="false" data-lazyLoad="true" data-nav="false" data-autoHeight="false"></div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6">
                <div class="single-flex">
                    <div class="single-product-info product-info product-grid-v2 s-50 js-price-wrapper">
                    <p class="product-cate"></p>
                    <div class="product-rating">
                       <span class="shopify-product-reviews-badge" data-id=""></span>
                    </div>
              

                <h3 class="product-title"><a>&nbsp;</a></h3>

                <div class="details clearfix">
                  <form action="/cart/add" method="post" class="variants CartContainer">
                    <div class="product-price">
                      <span class="price f-24"></span>
                      <span class="price old compare-price mr-10"></span>
                      

                    </div>


                    
                    <p class="product-desc"></p>
                    

                    <select name='id' style="display:none;" class="engoj-except-select2 product-single__variants">
                    
                    </select>
                    
                    <div class="single-product-button-group">

                        
                        <div class="e-btn cart-qtt">
                          <div class="e-quantity">
                            <input type="text" name="quantity" value="1" class="qty input-text product_quantity_number js-number">
                            <button  class='qtyminus quantity-left-minus btn btn-number js-minus ' data-field='quantity'><i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i></button>

                            <button class='qtyplus quantity-right-plus btn btn-number js-plus' data-field='quantity'><i class="fa fa-caret-up"></i></button>
                          </div>
                        <button type="button" class="btn-addToCart  btn-add-cart">{{ 'products.product.addtocart' | t }}<p class="icon-bg icon-cart v2"></p></button>

                        </div>
                        <div class="total-price product-price">
    <!--                       <label class="engoc_subtt_qw">{{ 'products.general.subtotal_price' | t }}:</label>
                          <span class="br-product__price fz-16"></span> -->
                        </div>



                    </div>
                  </form>
                </div>


              
            </div>
                </div>
            </div>
          </div>
      </div>
          
    </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<style>
  .single-product-detail .single-product-info .action .quantity {
    float: initial;
  }
</style>

<script type="text/javascript">
  Shopify.doNotTriggerClickOnThumb = false;
</script>
```

The code of (quickview.js) is

```
(function($) {
  function showPopup(selector) {
    $(selector).addClass('active'); 
  } window.showPopup=showPopup;

  function hidePopup(selector) {
    $(selector).removeClass('active');
  }

  function qtyProduct() {  
    $('.qtyplus').click(function(e){
      var fieldName = $(this).attr('data-field');
      var currentVal = parseInt($('input[name='+fieldName+']').val());

      if (!isNaN(currentVal)) {
        $('input[name='+fieldName+']').val(currentVal + 1);
      } else {
        $('input[name='+fieldName+']').val(1);
      }
      e.preventDefault();
    });

    $(".qtyminus").click(function(e) {

      var fieldName = $(this).attr('data-field');
      var currentVal = parseInt($('input[name='+fieldName+']').val());
      if (!isNaN(currentVal) && currentVal > 1) {
        $('input[name='+fieldName+']').val(currentVal - 1);    }
      else {
        $('input[name='+fieldName+']').val(1);
      }
      e.preventDefault();
    });
  }
  window.qtyProduct=qtyProduct;

  function doAjaxAddToCart(variant_id, quantity, title, image) {

    $.ajax({
      type: "post",
      url: "/cart/add.js",
      data: 'quantity=' + quantity + '&id=' + variant_id,
      dataType: 'json',
      beforeSend: function() {
        showPopup('.loading');
      },
      success: function(msg) {


        $('.tshopify-popup').removeClass('active');
        hidePopup('.quickview-product');
        Shopify.getCart(function(cart) {
          tbuildCart(cart);
        });
      },
      error: function(xhr, text) {
        hidePopup('.loading');
        $('.error-message').text($.parseJSON(xhr.responseText).description);
        showPopup('.error-popup');
      }
    });
  }window.doAjaxAddToCart=doAjaxAddToCart;

  function tbuildCart(cart) {
    // Start with a fresh cart div
    var $cartContainer = $('.enj-minicart-ajax');
    $cartContainer.empty();

    // Show empty cart
    if (cart.item_count === 0) {
      $cartContainer
      .append('<p>' + {{ 'cart.general.empty' | t | json }} + '</p>');
      cartCallback(cart);
      return;
    }

    // Handlebars.js cart layout
    var items = [],
        item = {},
        data = {},
        source = $("#CartTemplate").html(),
        template = Handlebars.compile(source);

    // Add each item to our handlebars.js data
    $.each(cart.items, function(index, cartItem) {

      /* Hack to get product image thumbnail
       *   - If image is not null
       *     - Remove file extension, add _small, and re-add extension
       *     - Create server relative link
       *   - A hard-coded url of no-image
      */
      if (cartItem.image != null){
        var prodImg = cartItem.image.replace(/(\.[^.]*)$/, "_small$1").replace('http:', '');
      } else {
        var prodImg = "//cdn.shopify.com/s/assets/admin/no-image-medium-cc9732cb976dd349a0df1d39816fbcc7.gif";
      }

      // Create item's data object and add to 'items' array
      item = {
        id: cartItem.variant_id,
        line: index + 1, // Shopify uses a 1+ index in the API
        url: cartItem.url,
        img: prodImg,
        name: cartItem.product_title,
        variation: cartItem.variant_title,
        properties: cartItem.properties,
        itemAdd: cartItem.quantity + 1,
        itemMinus: cartItem.quantity - 1,
        itemQty: cartItem.quantity,
        price: Shopify.formatMoney(cartItem.price, ajaxCartConfig.moneyFormat),
        vendor: cartItem.vendor
      };

      items.push(item);
    });

    // Gather all cart data and add to DOM
    data = {
      items: items,
      note: cart.note,
      totalPrice: Shopify.formatMoney(cart.total_price, ajaxCartConfig.moneyFormat)
    }

    $cartContainer.append(template(data));
    $('.enj-cartcount').html(cart.item_count);
    $('body').removeClass('drawer--is-loading');
    $('body').trigger('ajaxCart.afterCartLoad', cart);
  };

  function convertToSlug(text) {
    return text.toLowerCase().replace(/[^a-z0-9 -]/g, '').replace(/\s+/g, '-').replace(/-+/g, '-');
  } window.convertToSlug=convertToSlug;

  $(document).ready(function() {
    quickView();

  });

  $(document).on('click',' .overlay,.continue-shopping, .close-window', function() {
    hidePopup('.tshopify-popup');
    setTimeout(function(){
      $('.loading').removeClass('loaded-content');
    },500);
    return false;
  });


  function quickView() {
    $('.engoj_btn_quickview').click(function() {

      showPopup('.loading');
      var id = $(this).data('id');
      var rating = (($(this).closest('.product-info').find('.spr-badge').attr('data-rating')) * 20)+"%";

      Shopify.getProduct(id, function(product) {
        var template = $('#quick-view').html();
        $('.quickview-product').html(template);
        var quickview = $('.quickview-product');
        quickview.find('.product-title a').html(product.title).attr('href', product.url);
        quickview.find('.product-cate').html(product.type);
        quickview.find('.spr-badge .spr-active').css({"width": rating});
        if (quickview.find('.product-desc').length > 0) {
          var description = product.description.replace(/(<([^>]+)>)/ig, "");
          description = description.split(" ").splice(0, 20).join(" ") + "...";
          quickview.find('.product-desc').text(description);
        } else {
          quickview.find('.product-desc').remove();
        }

        quickview.find('.price').html(Shopify.formatMoney(product.price, window.money_format));
        quickview.find('.product-inner').attr('id', 'product-' + product.id);
        quickview.find('.variants').attr('id', 'product-actions-' + product.id);
        quickview.find('.variants select').attr('id', 'product-select-' + product.id);

        if (product.compare_at_price > product.price) {
          quickview.find('.compare-price').html(Shopify.formatMoney(currencyConverter(product.compare_at_price_max), window.money_format)).show();
          quickview.find('.price').addClass('on-sale');
        } else {
          quickview.find('.compare-price').html('');
          quickview.find('.price').removeClass('on-sale');
        }

        //out of stock
        if (!product.available) {
          quickview.find("select, input, .total-price, .dec, .inc, .variants label, .quantity-all, .e-quantity").remove();
          quickview.find(".btn-addToCart").parent().addClass('no-qtt').removeClass('btn-gradient');
          quickview.find(".btn-addToCart").text('Out of stock').addClass('btn-outofstock').attr("disabled", "disabled");
        } else {
          quickview.find('.total-price span').html(Shopify.formatMoney(currencyConverter(product.price), window.money_format));

          tshopifyQuickview.createQuickViewVariantsSwatch(product, quickview);
        }

        qtyProduct();
        tshopifyQuickview.quickViewSlider(product, quickview);
        tshopifyQuickview.initQuickviewAddToCart();


        $('.quickview-product').addClass('active');
        $('.loading').addClass('loaded-content');

        if ($('.quickview-product .total-price').length > 0) {
          $('.quickview-product button[class=js-plus]').on('click', tshopifyQuickview.updatePricingQuickview);
          $('.quickview-product button[class=js-minus]').on('click', tshopifyQuickview.updatePricingQuickview);
        }

        quickview.find('.owl-carousel').owlCarousel({
          items: quickview.find('.owl-carousel').attr('data-items'),
          dots: false
        })
      });
      return false;
    });
  } window.quickView=quickView;

  var tshopifyQuickview = {

    selectCallbackQuickview: function(variant, selector) {
      var self = this;
      var productItem = jQuery('.quickview-product .product-item'),
          addToCart = productItem.find('.btn-addToCart'),
          productPrice = productItem.find('.price'),
          comparePrice = productItem.find('.compare-price'),
          totalPrice = productItem.find('.total-price span');

      if (variant && variant.featured_image) {
        var originalImage = jQuery(".engoj_img_main_quickview");
        var newImage = variant.featured_image;
        var element = originalImage[0];
        Shopify.Image.switchImage(newImage, element, function (newImageSizedSrc, newImage, element) {
          var $el = $(element);
          $el.attr('src', newImageSizedSrc);
        });        
      }

      if (variant) {
        if (variant.available) {
          addToCart.removeClass('disabled').removeAttr('disabled').text('{{ 'products.product.add_to_cart' | t }}');
                                                                        } else {
                                                                        addToCart.val('sold_out').addClass('disabled').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
        }
        productPrice.html(Shopify.formatMoney(currencyConverter(variant.price), window.money_format));



        if ( variant.compare_at_price > variant.price ) {
          comparePrice.html(Shopify.formatMoney(currencyConverter(variant.compare_at_price), window.money_format)).show();
          productPrice.addClass('on-sale');
        } else {
          comparePrice.hide();
          productPrice.removeClass('on-sale');
        }

        var form = jQuery('#' + selector.domIdPrefix).closest('form');
        for (var i=0,length=variant.options.length; i<length; i++) {
          var radioButton = form.find('.swatch[data-option-index="' + i + '"] :radio[value="' + variant.options[i] +'"]');
          if (radioButton.size()) {
            radioButton.get(0).checked = true;
          }
        }


        var inventoryInfo = productItem.find('.product-inventory span');
        if (variant.available) {
          if (variant.inventory_management!=null) {
            inventoryInfo.text(variant.inventory_quantity + " " + 'in_stock');
          } else {
            inventoryInfo.text('many_in_stock');
          }
        } else {
          inventoryInfo.text('out_of_stock');
        }

        // Total:
        var regex = /([0-9]+[.|,][0-9]+[.|,][0-9]+)/g;
        var unitPriceTextMatch = $('.quickview-product .price').text().match(regex);

        if (!unitPriceTextMatch) {
          regex = /([0-9]+[.|,][0-9]+)/g;
          unitPriceTextMatch = $('.quickview-product .price').text().match(regex);
        }

        if (unitPriceTextMatch) {
          var unitPriceText = unitPriceTextMatch[0];
          var unitPrice = unitPriceText.replace(/[.|,]/g, '');
          var quantity = parseInt($('.quickview-product input[name=quantity]').val());
          var totalPrice = unitPrice * quantity;
          totalPrice = currencyConverter(totalPrice);

          var totalPriceText = Shopify.formatMoney(totalPrice, window.money_format);
          regex = /([0-9]+[.|,][0-9]+[.|,][0-9]+)/g;
          if (!totalPriceText.match(regex)) {
            regex = /([0-9]+[.|,][0-9]+)/g;
          }
          totalPriceText = totalPriceText.match(regex)[0];

          var regInput = new RegExp(unitPriceText, "g");
          var totalPriceHtml = $('.quickview-product .price').html().replace(regInput, totalPriceText);

          $('.quickview-product .total-price span').html(totalPriceHtml);
        }

        if (variant && variant.featured_image) {
          var newImage = Shopify.resizeImage(variant.featured_image.src, 'small');
          newImage = newImage.replace(/https?:/,'');
          jQuery('.quick-view .quickview-more-views img').each(function() {
            var grandSize = jQuery(this).attr('src');
            if (grandSize == newImage) {
              jQuery(this).parent().trigger('click');
              return false;
            }
          });
        }

      } else {
        addToCart.text('unavailable').addClass('disabled').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
      }

      Currency.convertAll(shopCurrency, jQuery('#currencies a.selected').attr('data-currency'));
      jQuery('.selected-currency').text(Currency.currentCurrency);

    },
    /* Quick View SWATCH */
    createQuickViewVariantsSwatch: function(product, quickviewTemplate) {
      var self = this;
      if (product.variants.length > 1) {
        for (var i = 0; i < product.variants.length; i++) {
          var variant = product.variants[i];
          var option = '<option value="' + variant.id + '">' + variant.title + '</option>';
          quickviewTemplate.find('form.variants > select').append(option);
        }

        new Shopify.OptionSelectors("product-select-" + product.id, {
          product: product,
          onVariantSelected: self.selectCallbackQuickview,
          enableHistoryState: true
        });

        var filePath = window.file_url.substring(0, window.file_url.lastIndexOf('?'));
        var assetUrl = window.asset_url.substring(0, window.asset_url.lastIndexOf('?'));
        var options = "";

        for (var i = 0; i < product.options.length; i++) {
          options += '<div class="swatch clearfix" data-option-index="' + i + '">';
          options += '<div class="header title_variant space_right_10">' + product.options[i].name + '</div>';
          var is_color = false;
          if (/Color|Colour/i.test(product.options[i].name)) {
            is_color = true;
          }
          var optionValues = new Array();
          for (var j = 0; j < product.variants.length; j++) {
            var variant = product.variants[j];
            var value = variant.options[i];
            var valueHandle = convertToSlug(value);
            var forText = 'swatch-' + i + '_' + valueHandle;
            if (optionValues.indexOf(value) < 0) {
              //not yet inserted
              options += '<div data-value="' + value + '" class="swatch-element ' + (is_color ? "color" : "") + valueHandle + (variant.available ? ' available ' : ' soldout ') + '">';

              if (is_color) {
                options += '<div class="tooltip">' + value + '</div>';
              }
              options += '<input id="' + forText + '" type="radio" name="option-' + i + '" value="' + value + '" ' + (j == 0 ? ' checked ' : '') + (variant.available ? '' : ' disabled') + ' />';

              if (is_color) {
                options += '<label class="variant_color variant_quickview" for="' + forText + '" ><span class="link_color"><span class="ciloe_filter_color" style="background-color: ' + valueHandle + ';"></span></span></label>';
              } else {
                options += '<label class="variant_other" for="' + forText + '">' + value + '</label>';
              }
              options += '</div>';
              if (variant.available) {
                $('.quickview-product .swatch[data-option-index="' + i + '"] .' + valueHandle).removeClass('soldout').addClass('available').find(':radio').removeAttr('disabled');
              }
              optionValues.push(value);
            }
          }
          options += '</div>';
        }
        quickviewTemplate.find('form.variants > select').after(options);
        quickviewTemplate.find('.swatch :radio').change(function() {
          var optionIndex = $(this).closest('.swatch').attr('data-option-index');
          var optionValue = $(this).val();
          $(this)
          .closest('form')
          .find('.single-option-selector')
          .eq(optionIndex)
          .val(optionValue)
          .trigger('change');
        });

        if (product.available && product.options.size > 1) {
          Shopify.optionsMap = {};
          Shopify.linkOptionSelectors(product);
        }

      } else {
        quickviewTemplate.find('form.variants > select').remove();
        var variant_field = '<input type="hidden" name="id" value="' + product.variants[0].id + '">';
        quickviewTemplate.find('form.variants').append(variant_field);
      }
    },

    /* Quick View */
    createQuickViewVariants: function(product, quickviewTemplate) {
      var self = this;
      if (product.variants.length > 1) {
        for (var i = 0; i < product.variants.length; i++) {
          var variant = product.variants[i];
          var option = '<option value="' + variant.id + '">' + variant.title + '</option>';
          quickviewTemplate.find('form.variants > select').append(option);
        }

        new Shopify.OptionSelectors("product-select-" + product.id, {
          product: product,
          onVariantSelected: self.selectCallbackQuickview,
          enableHistoryState: true
        });

        //$('.quickview-product .single-option-selector').selectize();
        $('.quickview-product .selectize-input input').attr("disabled", "disabled");

        if (product.options.length == 1) {
          $('.selector-wrapper:eq(0)').prepend('<label>' + product.options[0].name + '</label>');
        }

        quickviewTemplate.find('form.variants .selector-wrapper label').each(function(i, v) {
          $(this).html(product.options[i].name);
        });

      } else {
        quickviewTemplate.find('form.variants > select').remove();
        var variant_field = '<input type="hidden" name="id" value="' + product.variants[0].id + '">';
        quickviewTemplate.find('form.variants').append(variant_field);
      }

    },

    /* Quick View VIEWMORE Slider */
    quickViewSlider: function(product, quickviewTemplate) {
      var featuredImage = Shopify.resizeImage(product.featured_image, 'grande');
      quickviewTemplate.find('.featured-image').append('<a title="'+ product.title +'" class="product-photo" href="' + product.url + '"><img class="engoj_img_main_quickview" src="' + featuredImage + '" alt="' + product.title + '"/><span class="loading" style="height: 100%; width: 100%; top:0; left:0 z-index: 999; position: absolute; display: none; background: url(' + window.loading_url + ') center no-repeat;"></span></a>');
      if (product.images.length > 2) {
        var quickViewCarousel = quickviewTemplate.find('.more-views .owl-carousel');

        for (i in product.images) {
          var grande = Shopify.resizeImage(product.images[i], 'grande');
          var compact = Shopify.resizeImage(product.images[i], 'compact');
          var item = '<div class="item"><a href="javascript:void(0)" data-image="' + grande + '"><img src="' + compact + '"  /></a></div>';
          quickViewCarousel.append(item);
        }

        quickViewCarousel.find('a').click(function() {
          var featureImage = quickviewTemplate.find('.featured-image img');
          var moreviewLoad = quickviewTemplate.find('.featured-image .loading');
          if (featureImage.attr('src') != $(this).attr('data-image')) {
            featureImage.attr('src', $(this).attr('data-image'));
            moreviewLoad.show();
            featureImage.load(function(e) {
              moreviewLoad.hide();
              $(this).unbind('load');
              moreviewLoad.hide();
            });
          }
        });

      } else {
        quickviewTemplate.find('.more-views').remove();
      }

    },

    /* Quick View ADD TO CART */
    initQuickviewAddToCart: function() {
      if ($('.quickview-product .btn-addToCart').length > 0) {
        $('.quickview-product .btn-addToCart').click(function() {
          var variant_id = $('.quickview-product select[name=id]').val();
          if (!variant_id) {
            variant_id = $('.quickview-product input[name=id]').val();
          }
          var quantity = $('.quickview-product input[name=quantity]').val();
          if (!quantity) {
            quantity = 1;
          }

          var title = $('.quickview-product .product-title a').html();
          var image = $('.quickview-product .featured-image img').attr('src');

          doAjaxAddToCart(variant_id, quantity, title, image);

        });
      }
    },
    /* Quick View update Pricing */
    updatePricingQuickview: function() {
      var regex = /([0-9]+[.|,][0-9]+[.|,][0-9]+)/g;
      var unitPriceTextMatch = $('.js-price-wrapper .price').text().match(regex);

      if (!unitPriceTextMatch) {
        regex = /([0-9]+[.|,][0-9]+)/g;
        unitPriceTextMatch = $('.js-price-wrapper .price').text().match(regex);
      }

      if (unitPriceTextMatch) {
        var unitPriceText = unitPriceTextMatch[0];
        var unitPrice = unitPriceText.replace(/[.|,]/g, '');
        var quantity = parseInt($('.js-price-wrapper input[name=quantity]').val());
        var totalPrice = unitPrice * quantity;

        var totalPriceText = Shopify.formatMoney(totalPrice, window.money_format);
        regex = /([0-9]+[.|,][0-9]+[.|,][0-9]+)/g;
        if (!totalPriceText.match(regex)) {
          regex = /([0-9]+[.|,][0-9]+)/g;
        }
        totalPriceText = totalPriceText.match(regex)[0];

        var regInput = new RegExp(unitPriceText, "g");
        var totalPriceHtml = $('.js-price-wrapper .price').html().replace(regInput, totalPriceText);

        $('.js-price-wrapper .total-price span').html(totalPriceHtml);
      }
    }

  }
  })(jQuery);
```

Any help would be really appreciated. Thank you

I tried many methods but none of them really worked